# Binding To Collection Count

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to create a small button which displays the actual Count property of a custom class through binding. Here is my custom class code snippet:

```
public sealed class Counter : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    private List<MyClass> m_Collection;

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return m_Collection.Count; }
    }

    ...
```

Here is my Window code snippet:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_Counter = new Counter();
    }
```

Here is a XAML snippet of my MainWindow:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
...
   <Button Content="{Binding Path=m_Counter.Count}" Height="40" Width="40"/>
```

Mh... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on Counter and raise `PropertyChanged` with **Count** as the property name when you modify the `m_Collection`

Something like

```
public sealed class Counter : IEnumerable<MyClass> , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<MyClass> m_Collection;

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return m_Collection.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(MyClass item)
    {
        m_Collection.Add(item);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

You might have to fire it for all List mutation events.

The simpler thing is to do something like

```
 public sealed class Counter2 : IEnumerable<MyClass>
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyClass> m_Collection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Collection;
            }
        }

    }
```

and in XAML bind to `Collection.Count`